# Using jQuery to bind a click to the unused part of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck trying to bind a click redirect to the body tag on a page where there's not already another div.  I have a typical header, container and footer layout but I want to place a site skin in the background for users to click on to register.

Here's what I have so far to target the body element:

```
$('body').bind({
    click: function() {
        window.location = 'https://example.com/';
    },
})
```

The background image displays fine and the redirect works but if I click on somewhere in the header, container or footer it will perform the redirect which is not what I want.  I'd prefer it ignore those divs for purpose of the redirect.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Schlogen/rVBRy/)

```
$("body").click( function(e) {
    if(e.target == this)
    {
        window.location = 'https://example.com/';
    }
});​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `on()`:

```
$('body').on('click', ':not(div)', function(e){
    window.location = 'https://example.com/';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EVE5Y/).